# Twitter GET status count not working

Tags: json, twitter, get

I'm using jQuery to display a Twitter feed following a certain hashtag. Here's the url:

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&count=3&q=%23test&include_entities=true&include_rts=true

But it's returning 15 rows, instead of the 3 that I specified in the url (count=3)...Is there a new way to declare the count? [Here's the data in Jabulr](http://jabulr.com/?e=http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&count=3&q=%2523test&include_entities=true&include_rts=true).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the [Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) doesn't support the `count` parameter.

The REST API [GET search/tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets) does, but using that is a bit more complicated, since all requests need to be authenticated by March 2013, i.e. in a little more than a week from now.

Comment: Aha, I was going off of the GET statuses/user_timeline docs https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: Performance-wise, do you think it's a bad idea to just hide all rows except for 3 using css?

Comment: Well, it's a slight overhead in the amount of data transported over the wire, but I doubt it's unmanageable. If you think it's too much, I'd look into using the REST API.

Comment: Hmm okay. I can't even get Jabulr to read deal with the REST API url scheme. It's a json feed so that's odd.

Comment: That's because you need a token to use the V1.1. V1 will still work for a week or so. Read the docs about authentication.